# replacing add to cart button with paypal checkout in woocommerce only on shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, hook-woocommerce

I want to replace add to cart button with paypal express checkout button in shop page of woocommerce 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWMUU.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: honestly nothing
i couldnt find the right file for it 
i am still looking for it

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of plugins that can do this for you, if you want to use that solution. This does what you're looking for:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/express-checkout/

Then you also have another plugin that does this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/

But there has been some reported issues with this like when you press it with nothing in your cart, it just says your cart is empty. If you have items in your cart already, it will send you to PayPal correctly, but it doesn't add the item in question.

I've added PayPal to WooCom before, and it worked fine, but not like what you're trying to do, I did this in the checkout process.

Comment: i have a paypal plugin added to my woocommerce and it shows the paypal button to buy the product from paypal checkout 
and i want similar button instead of that button